# Facebook Instant Games - Can I use the camera in my instant game

Tags: facebook, instant

Is it possible to get access to the camera in the Instant Game?
I tried navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia, but got an NotAllowedError, permission denied.

Am I doing something wrong?
If not, are there plans from Facebook to allow access to the camera?

Comment: `navigator.mediaDevices` itself has nothing to do specifically with Facebook; so unless they are somehow overwriting this object with their own implementation, I’d say it probably is rather not Facebook denying access here in the first place ...

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to use the camera (via `getUserMedia` or related APIs) in Instant Games. This is not a limitation that we (Facebook) apply to Instant Games but a limitation of the system web views on Android and iOS that limit this functionality.

There are no immediate plans to incorporate the camera into Instant Games, however there is opportunity with camera games and we do support simple game development in AR Studio, such as [the Candy Crush effect that was released last year](http://www.adweek.com/digital/king-launched-a-gamified-facebook-lens-based-on-candy-crush-saga/).

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. There's no way to access the camera or take pictures in any way in an "Instant Games" ? Or is there a way that I did not understand ?

Comment: Updated my answer to make it clearer that it is not possible due to limitations on the native webviews on iOS and Android.

Comment: Most browsers Deprecating permissions to use camera, in Cross-Origin iframe. Since Facebook runs the instant game inside iframe, navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia will always come up with error unless iframe tag has "Feature Policy" specified.